# Will a wifi range extender work after AAA configuration of the network?

Tags: wifi, aaa, repeater

In our campus LAN we are using WPA2 protocol and users have a common password.

Presently there are several WAPs but we also need a few wifi range extenders (the range extender is TP Link TL- WA855RE) to cover the blind spots in areas we can't install WAPs.

We want to get AAA configuration to secure the network. My question is - will we be able to use the range extenders after AAA configuration. I have very limited knowledge of networking and I have tried to describe my question with this limited knowledge please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the cost of $25, you could easily and affordably test the scenario. However, as long as the device simply repeats the signal and does not do anything to modify the signal/data, it will work and the original AP will not know the difference (and AAA will continue to work).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tod. Yes we have tested the device and it is good for our requirement. Cheers.